# Post facebook event on group wall

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to post an event on a group wall-

```
try 
{
   $ret_obj = $facebook->api($groupId.'/feed', 'POST',
                          array(
                           'link' => 'https://www.facebook.com/events/EVENT_ID/')); 

} 
catch(FacebookApiException $e) 
{
}
```

this code post successfully the event but it doesn't appear properly on the group .
it only show the name of the event,but doesnt show picture,details and more...

ps: it work properly on page wall and i have chech my group permissions 
tell me what wrong,is it a facebook issue ??

Answer (score 0):

Facebook might not be able to fetch the details from the link; you can manually set the other parameters-

```
array(
        'lik' => 'https://www.facebook.com/events/EVENT_ID/',
        'picture' => PICTURE_URL,
        'description' => DESC,
        'caption' => CAPTION  ));
```